# Java Lazy Stream of Strings including List<String>

Tags: java, list, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I'm creating a Stream of String lazily, for the first two simple items. However, part of my stream is List of String.

```
Stream<String> streamA = Stream.concat(
      Stream.generate(item::getStringA),
      Stream.generate(item::getStringB))

return Stream.concat(streamA, item.getStringList(param).stream())
```

The above works, but .getStringList needs to be called lazily as well. It's not clear to me how to fetch it and "merge" it in with the rest of the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, what you actually want to do, is

```
return Stream.<Supplier<Stream<String>>>of(
    () -> Stream.of(item.getStringA()),
    () -> Stream.of(item.getStringB()),
    () -> item.getStringList(param).stream())
    .flatMap(Supplier::get);
```

This produces a fully lazy `Stream<String>` where, e.g. `.limit(0).count()` will not call any method on `item` or `.findFirst()` will only invoke `getStringA()`, etc.

The stream’s *content* will be equivalent to

```
Stream.concat(
    Stream.of(item.getStringA(), item.getStringB()), item.getStringList(param).stream())
```

Comment: findFirst() is exactly what I wanted this for. While Louis' answer works, I feel this is a bit more intuitive at least to a "stream newbie".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any of this does what you think it does.  `Stream.generate` *always* generates an *infinite* stream.  But the closest thing to what you want is going to be

```
StreamSupport.stream(() -> item.getStringList(param).spliterator(), 0, false)
```

...which will lazily call `item.getStringList(param)`.  (What you want isn't really an intended use case of `Stream`, so it's not very well supported.)

Comment: I started realizing how far off I was. However, I don't think I ever would have found that StreamSupport method. It seems like stream is the natural fit for what I'm doing, but it does seem a little shoe-horned using that method.

Comment: Note that `StreamSupport.stream(Supplier…)` will defer the invocation to the point when the terminal operation commences, but passing the stream to `Stream.concat` already has the effect of terminating the stream. So it’s not as lazy as you might think. Further, you should never pass arbitrary characteristics like `0` to it. The specification clearly states that the characteristics must be identical to the spliterator’s characteristics, so you should precisely know what you are doing when using this method. When the source is a `List`, they have to include at least `ORDERED | SIZED | SUBSIZED`

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is return a `Stream` from your `item.getStringList()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Item item = new Item();
    Stream<String> a = Stream.concat(Stream.of("A"), Stream.of("B"));

    Stream<String> anotherStream = Stream.concat(a, item.getStringList());


    anotherStream.forEach(System.out::println);
}

private static class Item {

    public Stream<String> getStringList() {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

        l.add("C");
        l.add("D");
        l.add("E");
        l.add("F");
        final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        return Stream.iterate(l.get(i.get()), (f) -> {
            // Proof of laziness
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return l.get(i.getAndIncrement());
        })
        // Iterate is by default unbound
        .limit(l.size());
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how helpful that approach would be still, since your list is still in the memory.